# Interesting theoretic proof with polynomials

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing

Four polynomials with real coefficients $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ are given. The sum of any two of them has no real roots. Prove that if the polynomial $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4$ has a real root, then at least one of the polynomials $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ doesn't have a real root. $$$$
Unfortunately I'm quite new to polynomials and don't have the best understanding of them, so I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me through this with explanation.

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? Was there any context involved? It would help to know what sort of tools you might be expected to solve this problem with.

Comment: Nothing additional about the degrees of the $p_k$s ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I mean, you can assume they all have even degree WLOG.

Comment: Does this post help with your problem?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578580/

Comment: Maybe use the fact that a polynomial with no real roots is either of the form $P(x)^2+Q(x)^2$ or of the form $-(P(x)^2+Q(x)^2)$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/823627)

Comment: @DonThousand Couldn't one of them have odd degree?

Comment: No, because then it would have a real root, which would finish the question immediately.

Comment: @DonThousand Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see why. The sum of every pair could still have no real roots (since those can all be even degree e.g. if $p_1$ is cubic and $p_2, p_3, p_4$ quartic) and we're being asked to show that at least one of the $p$ has no real roots, so knowing that e.g. $p_1$ must have a real root doesn't tell us anything about the other $p_i$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, actually, I can't read. I read it as at least one of the polynomials has a real root. Oops

Comment: No worries! I'm glad I wasn't missing anything obvious. (In fact, I believe one could in principle even have two polynomials with odd degree, if the other two have higher even degrees and the two odd-degree polynomials have additively inverse leading coefficients — then all pairwise sums could have even degree and so potentially have no real roots)

Answer (score 1):

Let us use the fact that a polynomial with no real roots can be represented by one of the two forms:

- $\ \ \ P(x)^2+Q(x)^2$ [case (+)] ($P$ and $Q$ having no common roots).
- $−(P(x)^2+Q(x)^2)$ [case (-)]

(see [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/823627)), corresponding to the cases where the dominant coefficient is positive (resp. negative).

The first hypothesis means that

$$p_1+p_2, \ \ \ \ p_1+p_3, \ \ \ \ p_1+p_4, \ \ \ \  p_2+p_3,  \ \ \ \ p_2+p_4,  \ \ \ \ p_3+p_4$$

are each one either in case (+) or in case (-).

Let us assume that

$$p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4 \ \ \ \text{has a real root.}\tag{1}$$

Therefore, we have as many (+) and (-) cases (see Remark 1 below), like this:

$$\begin{cases}(a)&p_1+p_2&=&A^2+B^2\\(b)&p_3+p_4&=&-(C^2+D^2)\end{cases}, 
\ \ \begin{cases}(c)&p_1+p_3&=&E^2+F^2\\(d)&p_2+p_4&=&-(G^2+H^2)\end{cases}, \ \ \begin{cases}(e)&p_1+p_4&=&I^2+J^2\\(f)&p_2+p_3&=&-(K^2+L^2)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

for certain polynomials $A,B,C,\cdots K,L$.

Combining (a)+(c)-(f), one gets

$$2p_1=A^2+B^2+E^2+F^2+K^2>0, \ \ \text{therefore with no real roots} \tag{3}$$

as was desired.

**Remark 1:** In (2), if we have had for example $$\begin{cases}(a)&p_1+p_2&=&A^2+B^2\\(b)&p_3+p_4&=&(C^2+D^2)\end{cases},$$ the sum $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4$ would have always been $>0$, contradicting (1).

**Remark 2:** One could object that the cases considered in (2) are one among many. In fact, we can WLOG attribute indices to the $p_k$s in such a way that equations (a),(b),(c),(d) hold. It remains the last two equations (e) and (f) for which we could have a (+) sign for (f) and (-) sign for (e). The reader will not have difficulty to see that in this case as well, one can conclude as in (3).

Comment: Some comments on this solution ?